# How do I dynamically generate a sitemap with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, sitemap

My website changes every day - I run a news website with new stories every day. I want Google to index my site as often as possible and want/need to autogenerate the sitemap.

I use Google App Engine (with Node.js) to run my site. With GAE - I do not have write-access to the root directory. To post the site map - I need to re-deploy my whole site after generating the map.  That is an unnecessarily complex step.

I have searched far and wide and cannot see how to save my sitemap. So - I considered using a static one with a dynamically generated child that I store in another location where I have write access.  Google says it wants all linked sitemaps in the same directory. So that appears to be a dead-end.

Can I use "App Deploy" in such a way that only the sitemap is uploaded?  Any other possibilities?  Appreciate any and all suggestions. It seems unlikely that Google didn't provide some way to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Engine Dynamically Generated Sitemap with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474042/google-app-engine-dynamically-generated-sitemap-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

For a site where new URLs are being created regularly (like a news, blog site, etc), don't 'store' your sitemap. It should be generated on demand i.e. your App should include code to generate the content when the link `<your_website>/sitemap.xml` is loaded.

Separately, you should note that `gcloud app deploy` doesn't always deploys all your files. It usually deploys **only** files that have changed. You can easily confirm this by running the deploy command, changing a **single** file and then running the deploy command again. You will see that the logs will say something like - `Uploading 1 files to Google Cloud Storage` and the deploy will be faster. You can change `X` number of files, deploy again and the message will be updated to indicate it is only deploying `x` files.

However, I'm not sure what it uses to compute the diff. Maybe it compares it to the files currently in your staging bucket and if the files in the staging bucket have been deleted (they have a default life span of 15 days) it will deploy all the files again (but as I said, I'm not sure of this)

Comment: Thanks - that is an interesting angle - I will give it a try. I should be able to create a route for that path in Node.